# Generate XRD pole figure using ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I have a data file consisting of radial, angle, and intensity columns. For each radius value, angle moves a full rotation while collecting intensity. With `ListDensityPlot`, I could plot it as given below

[image: list density plot]

```
ListDensityPlot[
  data, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"χ (°)", "Φ (°)"},
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> Plain, FontFamily -> Helvetica}
]
```

Now I would like to plot it in a polar plot as shown in the following figure.

[image: sample polar plot]

Here's a sample of data that shows angles in degrees (columns 1 and 2), and intensity measurement in column 3:

```
{{0, -6.572, 4}, {0, 193.428, 6}, {1.5, 32.428, 4}, {1.5, 232.428, 7}, {3, 71.428, 7}, {3, 271.428, 3}, {4.5, 110.428, 6}, {4.5, 310.428, 6}, {6, 149.428, 7}, {6, 349.428, 3}, {7.5, 188.428, 2}, {9, 27.428, 8}, {9, 227.428, 6}, {10.5, 66.428, 8}, {10.5, 266.428, 6}, {12, 105.428, 4}, {12, 305.428, 4}, {13.5, 144.428, 5}, {13.5, 344.428, 6}, {15, 183.428, 5}, {16.5, 22.428, 5}, {16.5, 222.428, 1}, {18, 61.428, 2}, {18, 261.428, 4}, {19.5, 100.428, 5}, {19.5, 300.428, 6}, {21, 139.428, 6}, {21, 339.428, 2}, {22.5, 178.428, 2}, {24, 17.428, 3}, {24, 217.428, 4}, {25.5, 56.428, 4}, {25.5, 256.428, 6}, {27, 95.428, 3}, {27, 295.428, 8}, {28.5, 134.428, 4}, {28.5, 334.428, 5}, {30, 173.428, 6}, {31.5, 12.428, 4}, {31.5, 212.428, 2}, {33, 51.428, 0}, {33, 251.428, 4}, {34.5, 90.428, 2}, {34.5, 290.428, 3}, {36, 129.428, 5}, {36, 329.428, 3}, {37.5, 168.428, 4}, {39, 7.428, 7}, {39, 207.428, 1}, {40.5, 46.428, 3}, {40.5, 246.428, 3}, {42, 85.428, 3}, {42, 285.428, 11}, {43.5, 124.428, 0}, {43.5, 324.428, 3}, {45, 163.428, 1}, {46.5, 2.428, 4}, {46.5, 202.428, 5}, {48, 41.428, 2}, {48, 241.428, 3}, {49.5, 80.428, 4}, {49.5, 280.428, 3}, {51, 119.428, 4}, {51, 319.428, 3}, {52.5, 158.428, 4}, {54, -2.572, 5}, {54, 197.428, 2}, {55.5, 36.428, 2}, {55.5, 236.428, 2}, {57, 75.428, 3}, {57, 275.428, 6}, {58.5, 114.428, 6}, {58.5, 314.428, 5}, {60, 153.428, 1}, {60, 353.428, 0}, {61.5, 192.428, 1}, {63, 31.428, 1}, {63, 231.428, 3}, {64.5, 70.428, 3}, {64.5, 270.428, 5}, {66, 109.428, 3}, {66, 309.428, 3}, {67.5, 148.428, 2}, {67.5, 348.428, 2}, {69, 187.428, 6}, {70.5, 26.428, 2}, {70.5, 226.428, 0}, {72, 65.428, 1}, {72, 265.428, 1}, {73.5, 104.428, 5}, {73.5, 304.428, 2}, {75, 143.428, 1}, {75, 343.428, 0}, {76.5, 182.428, 2}, {78, 21.428, 0}, {78, 221.428, 3}, {79.5, 60.428, 3}, {79.5, 260.428, 3}, {81, 99.428, 6}, {81, 299.428, 3}, {82.5, 138.428, 2}, {82.5, 338.428, 1}, {84, 177.428, 5}, {85.5, 16.428, 3}, {85.5, 216.428, 4}, {87, 55.428, 1}, {87, 255.428, 2}, {88.5, 94.428, 0}, {88.5, 294.428, 2}, {90, 133.428, 3}, {90, 333.428, 0}};
```

The entire data set is available at [pastebin.com/RWHDfL6u](https://pastebin.com/RWHDfL6u).

---

*[The following was provided by the OP in a suggested edit to an answer; since it contains new information possibly useful to answering the question, I am trying to salvage it by including it here - MarcoB]*

I do not want the data to be transformed. Please see the below image for clarity.

[image: example of desired pole figure]

It is called the XRD pole figure. Angle Chi (1st column of my data varied from 0 to 90) is set along the radial axis, the second column is the angular (Phi 0 to 360) direction and the third one is intensity. Hope it is feasible with Mathematica.

[image: Added picture which I draw. Hope it helps to understand]

Comment: Please share your data or sample data in the same format, so we can more easily try things out.

Comment: @MarcoB - Thanks. Data file is too big that I am unable to send it. Is there a way to attach data file here.

Comment: @MarcoB I have added partial data as per the max limit

Comment: What is the relation  of  `{a,b,c}` in your data?

Comment: It doesn’t have a relation . ‘a’changes from 0 to 90, for each a value ‘b’ varies from 0 to 360 while acquiring ‘c’ which is intensity.

Comment: @MalliTangi Please go to e.g. https://pastebin.com/ and add your data there, then add a link to your question. The data you posted is too limited to play with.

Comment: @MarcoB. Thanks. Please find below for the linik

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RWHDfL6u

Comment: @MalliTangi I've taken the liberty of including your edit to my answer into your question, so everyone can see your clarification. It still seems to me that what you describe is exactly what we have done though, so I still don't understand how the "pole figure" is to be constructed. Maybe an example could help. Take one point from your raw data and tell us where is should end up in the pole figure (at which coordinates); that might help us understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

```
data;
newdata = 
  Function[{χ, ϕ, 
     z}, {(χ Degree)*Cos[ϕ Degree], (χ Degree)*
      Sin[ϕ Degree], z}] @@@ data;
ListDensityPlot[newdata, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"χ (°)", "Φ (°)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> Plain, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, InterpolationOrder -> Automatic, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 <= .2^2], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

**Original**
Maybe something like this.

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{χ, ϕ, Sin[χ*ϕ]}, {χ, 0., 4, 
     0.1}, {ϕ, 0., 2 Pi, 0.1}], 1];
newdata = 
  Apply[Function[{χ, ϕ, 
     z}, {χ Cos[ϕ], χ Sin[ϕ], z}], data, 1];
ListDensityPlot[newdata, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"χ (°)", "Φ (°)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> Plain, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, InterpolationOrder -> Automatic, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]]
```

Comment: I have added sample data. Please let me know your suggestion

Comment: Mathematica community has to introduce ListDensityPolarPlot for plotting {x,y,z} like Cartesian coordinates data  as a polar figure. I am eagerly waiting for this. I could not get help yet :) I thought it must be simple but it is not.

Comment: @MalliTangi  Maybe you want `Spherical` instead of `Polar` ?

Answer (score 4):

The data represents intensity measurements on the surface of a sphere. The pole-plot is a view of the surface of the sphere looking at the origin from the positive z-axis. For `ListDensityPlot`, we need to project points on the surface of the sphere (blue point) onto the x-y plane (red point).

[image: spherical coordinates]

`FromSphericalCoordinates` gives the *x*,*y*,*z* coordinates. Ignore the *z*-axis because ListDensityPlot needs only the *x*-*y* coordinates. We find this expression for the *x* and *y* coordinates:

```
FromSphericalCoordinates[{1, \[CapitalChi], \[CapitalPhi]}][[1 ;; 2]]
```

> {Cos[Φ] Sin[], Sin[Φ] Sin[]}

The first two columns of the data are degree measurements. Convert these two columns because `Sin` and `Cos` require radian values. Find the spherical coordinates projected onto the *x*-*y* plane. Borrowing from MarcoB's answer, plot the intensity measurements with `ListDensityPlot`, with radius circles at 15° intervals (15, 30, 45, and 60), and radial grid lines.

```
data[[All, 1 ;; 2]] *= Degree;
(*data projected onto the x-y plane*)
xyData = Function[{\[CapitalChi], \[CapitalPhi], intensity},
  {Cos[\[CapitalPhi]] Sin[\[CapitalChi]], 
    Sin[\[CapitalPhi]] Sin[\[CapitalChi]], intensity}] @@@ data;

intensityThreshold = 12;
ListDensityPlot[xyData,
 ColorFunction -> (Tanh[# - intensityThreshold] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Axes -> False, Frame -> False,
 Epilog -> {Thickness[0.01], Darker@Green, Circle[{0, 0}, 1],
   Thickness[0.005], Dashed,
   Table[Line[{p, -p}], {p,Table[{Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, 
     Subdivide[0, 150, 5] Degree(*30° increments*)}]}],
   Table[Circle[{0, 0}, Sin[d Degree]], {d, 15, 60, 15}]}]
```

[image: plot of spherical data]

Comment: and @ MarcoB. Thanks a lot for your help. Now I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for posting your complete data. You can transform your data into cartesian coordinates easily. Assuming that your dataset is `data`, then:

```
transformed = 
  Function[{rho, theta, intensity}, {rho Cos[theta], rho Sin[theta], intensity}] @@@ data;
```

This can be digested by `ListDensityPlot` directly. Below I have added a sigmoidal shaper to the `ColorFunction`, acting directly on your intensity values. You should play around with the `intensityThreshold` until you find a value that you think best highlights the features of your data set. You might want to use `Manipulate` for this as well.

```
With[{intensityThreshold = 12},
  ListDensityPlot[
    transformed,
    ColorFunction -> (Tanh[# - intensityThreshold] &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    ImageSize -> Medium,
    Epilog -> {Thickness[0.01], Darker@Green, 
               Circle[{0, 0}, Max[transformed[[All, 2]]]]},
    Axes -> False, Frame -> False
  ]
]
```

[image: radial density plot]

Comment: @ MarcoB, can you please have a quick look over the image I have added to give clear idea so that you can help. Feel free to let me know if you need more information. Thanks much for your time

Comment: @MalliTangi It still seems to me that what you describe is exactly what we have done though, so I still don't understand how the "pole figure" is to be constructed. Maybe an example could help. Take one point from your raw data and tell us where is should end up in the pole figure (at which coordinates); that might help us understand.

Comment: I have drawn the pole figure hope it will give you a clear idea now. Looking forward for your reply. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ MarcoB, I would like to see Chi and Phi scales as shown in the drawn figure. In your transformed data, I see both X and Y scales varying from +90 to -90. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: May I please know if there is any method other than ListDensityPLot ?